# Laravel Mix: Wrong css properties when running npm production

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

#### Environment

- Laravel Mix Version: laravel-mix@2.1.0
- Node Version: v8.2.1
- NPM Version: 6.10.0
- OS: Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

#### Description:

I'm trying to identify which CSS process is the culprit of some wrong CSS being applied with `npm run production` but I'm not being able to do it. Some Bootstrap 4 CSS properties are being translated/simplified and it's producing wrong styles. I tried a lot of solutions (in my local webpack.mix.js => mix.options). I've tried to disable purifyCss (I discovered it's not using it), uglify, force outputStyle to 'expanded' (in `.sass()` method), etc. None of them worked.

As a workaround, I could add a new "prod" ENV and perform minification and other things directly from my webpack.mix.js, but I don't like this solution, specially when I think it's just because of a setting/flag somewhere I could easily change (if I knew which one).

Thank you.

#### Steps To Reproduce:

`npm run dev`: `background-position: center right calc(0.375em + 0.1875rem)`

`npm run production`: `background-position: 100% calc(.375em + .1875rem)`

Comment: I don't get your ruleset. As far as i know we don't have 3-Value syntax in background position.

Comment: @mhrabiee that rule was inside Bootstrap 4.3.1 I can see it was fixed recently: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/de1a6e3201a2f047c5abd2430795be32d37e9a35#diff-4fcf7dc3cf66b28cb08274cc30798d70 I'll update my local version and close this post. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like it was a bug in a mixin:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/commit/de1a6e3201a2f047c5abd2430795be32d37e9a35#diff-4fcf7dc3cf66b28cb08274cc30798d70

https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/712

Updating to latest Bootstrap version solves the issue.